# AWS SES IAM policy to restrict a recipient is not working the way I expect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am using AWS Simple Email Service (SES), however I want to have a very tightly restricted policy.
I want to set up a policy to

- only be able to send emails to a domain (mydomain)
- from a specific (internal@mydomain.com) email address
- using a specific configuration set (internalonly)

I have tried the entry below, but it is not restricting the recipients. I cant see what Im doing wrongly.

Ive been chewing this one for a few days, and need some help. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:999999999:identity/internal@mydomain.com",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ses:FromAddress": "internal@mydomain.com"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "ses:Recipients": "*@mydomain.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:99999999999:configuration-set/internalonly",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ses:FromAddress": "internal@mydomain.com"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "ses:Recipients": "*@mydomain.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Following applying the policy, I tested this using the details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html

Sample test file ses-internal.txt

```
EHLO mydomain.com
AUTH LOGIN
Base64EncodedSMTPUserName
Base64EncodedSMTPPassword
MAIL FROM: internal@mydomain.com
RCPT TO: internal@mydomain.com
DATA
X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: internalonly
From: PM Access <internal@mydomain.com>
To: luke@otherdomain.com
Subject: Amazon SES SMTP Test to luke

This message was sent using the Amazon SES SMTP interface.

.
QUIT
```

Testing: works when it should prevent me sending to luke@otherdomain.com

```
% openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.<region>.amazonaws.com:587 < ses-internal.txt
depth=4 C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=3 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = email-smtp.<region>.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
250 Ok
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
235 Authentication successful.
250 Ok
250 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
250 Ok 01020184133e8041-ba607190-5bf0-4610-9280-bbc38b9cb074-000000
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
```

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for the suggestion @baduker

More reading and I found the mistake.
A) The "ses:Recipients" should be an array
B) The test file I was using has a schoolboy SMTP error in it. The To: field is documentary, the RCPT TO: field is the real recipient.

**Here is the complete solution**

1. The correct IAM rule:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1: 999999999999:identity/internal@mydomain.com",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ses:FromAddress": "internal@mydomain.com"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "ses:Recipients": [
                        "*@mydomain.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1: 999999999999:configuration-set/internalonly",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ses:FromAddress": "internal@mydomain.com"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "ses:Recipients": [
                        "*@mydomain.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. The correct test file

```
EHLO propertymonitor.com
AUTH LOGIN
Base64EncodedSMTPUserName
Base64EncodedSMTPPassword
MAIL FROM: internal@mydomainm.com
RCPT TO: luke@otherdomain.com
DATA
X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: internalonly
From: PM Access <internal@propertymonitor.com>
Subject: Amazon SES SMTP Test to luke

This message was sent using the Amazon SES SMTP interface.

.
QUIT
```

3. The command:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:587 < ses-internal-fail.txt
```

4. Running it gives the desired results:

```
depth=4 C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=3 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
250 Ok
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
334 XXXXXX
334 YYYYYY
235 Authentication successful.
250 Ok
250 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
554 Access denied: User `arn:aws:iam::999999999:user/ses-internal-user' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:999999999:identity/internal@mydomain.com'
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this policy a try and see if the recipients are getting restricted?

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AuthorizeAWS",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:999999999999:identity/internal@mydomain.com",
      "Action":[
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "ses:FromAddress":"internal@mydomain.com"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid":"AuthorizeInternal",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:999999999999:identity/internal@mydomain.com",
      "Action":[
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Condition":{
        "ForAllValues:StringLike":{
          "ses:Recipients":"*@mydomain.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, please note that *to use a configuration set when sending an email, you must pass the name of the configuration set in the headers of the email*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you can see I found the answer wasn't the IAM it was my very rusty SMTP